# How to identify a specific Ajax request when there are multiples Ajax request with Vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to run an Ajax request after another Ajax request has fired.  If there are multiple Ajax request(Requests A and B, and I want to fire request C if A is fired.) in the same page, how can I target the request I want?  What do I need to run to fill up the code below?

```
xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange', function(event) {
  if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200 && Request A fired) {
  Make Request C;
  }
});
```

I am looking for a solution without jQuery.

Comment: When do you want request `b` to be made?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a system to make xhr requests synchronously. Try nested promises, where next request is made when previous promise resolves.

```
let promiseA = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(resolve, 100, 'foo');
});

promiseA.then((x) => {
    // Launch request B
}).then((x) => {
    // Launch request C
}).then((x) => {
    // Launch request D....
});
```

[There's a good explanation on that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Answer (score 0):

You could make your request into a function that accepts a `callback` function. This function is called whenever the request is completed and will continue your code with the data that is received.

```
function request(url, callback) {
  const xhr = new XMLHTTPRequest();
  xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange', function(event) {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200 && typeof callback === 'function') {
      callback(xhr.responseText);
    }
  });
  xhr.open('GET', url, true);
  xhr.send();
}
```

It would work like this with nested callbacks and can be shuffled in any order that you would like.

```
request('request-a', function(dataA) {
  // Request A has finished here.
  // Now start request B.
  // dataA is the xhr.responseText value.

  request('request-b', function(dataB) {
    // Request B has finished here.
    // Now start request C.

    request('request-c', function(dataC) {
      // Request C has finished here.
    });

  });

});
```

This is the simplest way to make your request reusable and to act whenever your request has been finished. A more modern approach would be to use the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch), which is a promise based interface that does the same thing as `XMLHTTPRequest`. Be sure to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Use [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and [async await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) to make your life easier.

```js
async function handlerA() { 
    log('Starting request A...')
    let responseA = await fetch(urls.a)
    let a = await responseA.text()
    log('Starting request C...')
    let responseC = await fetch(urls.c)
    let c = await responseC.text()
    log(a + c)
}

async function handlerB() { 
    log('Starting request B...')
    let responseB = await fetch(urls.b)
    let b = await responseB.text()
    log(b)
}

const urls = {
  a: 'https://httpbin.org/json',
  b: 'https://httpbin.org/robots.txt',
  c: 'https://httpbin.org/xml',
}

function log(str) {
  document.getElementById('output').innerText += `${str}\n`
}

document.getElementById('btnA').addEventListener('click', handlerA)
document.getElementById('btnB').addEventListener('click', handlerB)
```

```html
<button id="btnA">Button A</button>
<button id="btnB">Button B</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that serves my need.  Simply creates another XMLRequest object and use them in the if statement.

```
let requestA = new XMLHttpRequest();
let requestB = new XMLHttpRequest();

if(requestA.readyState === 4){
//Run request C
}
```